# Invalid path error while cloning the repo from Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I got this error while cloning the repo, what can I do? 
`error: invalid path 'docs/2022/changelog_20220125_00:07_bj.md' fatal: unable to checkout working tree warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/`

Comment: Did you try doing what git suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character `:` is invalid in a path on Windows.

A workaround is to clone the repository without checkout,

```
git clone $repourl --no-checkout
```

and then checkout all files except the invalid one,

```
cd $repopath
git checkout master -- ':!docs/2022/changelog_20220125_00?07_bj.md'
```

`':!docs/2022/changelog_20220125_00?07_bj.md'` is a pathspec to exclude the path. `:` is replaced with the glob character `?` in order to avoid an error.

Run `git status` and it shows `docs/2022/changelog_20220125_00:07_bj.md` is staged as a removed file.

If this repository is also maintained on Windows, it's better to rename the invalid path on an OS where `:` is valid and the path can be checked out.