# how to replace whitespace with dashes in file names in git subfolder?

Tags: git

i have git repo of my sql, leetcode solved questions with many filenames with spaces like "my solution for exercise 1. py",  1 subfolder has even cyrillic names.

because of cyrillic and whitespace in file names i cant properly git clone to my local machine - it fails exactly in that subfolder. There are about 300 such files and adding "-" or "_" manually is tedious.

how to add - or "_" in filenames in that specific folder? the git [subfolder](https://github.com/erjan/coding_exercises/tree/master/itresume)

error:

```
Resolving deltas:  99% (5120/5171)
Resolving deltas: 100% (5171/5171)
Resolving deltas: 100% (5171/5171), done.
error: invalid path 'itresume/Pandas: Агрегирование продаж и возвратов.py'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Comment: To clarify, you need to rename files _without_ checking out a working tree, right?

Comment: i have about 12k files , short snippets, i can check out a working tree, but it fails at that subfolder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67878799/7976758 The problem with your path is that it contains a colon, not Cyrillic nor spaces -- colon. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76366224/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+invalid+path+warning%3A+Clone+succeeded%2C+but+checkout+failed.